# Is there a way I can map source code from TFS to local system using c#?

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to map source code folders from TFS to local system. I would like to make this  automated so that I can run on daily basis. and that is the reason I am trying to get it done via C#
Is that possible via C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i suggest you to use `Workspace.Get method` or `VersionControlServer.GetItems`

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.get.aspx

sample : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/579484/Access-Team-Foundation-Server-2